# How to delete a proportion of files?

Tags: command-line, backup, delete

I have a backup directory on a server that takes daily backups. That results in a lot of data which I want to purge whilst still keeping some of the backups.

Essentially a round robin system.

I am looking for a command that deletes a proportion of the files randomly (for instance, delete 80% of the files randomly.

Comment: Why you need to delete backup files randomly? Isn't it a better idea to delete the backup files older than two weeks (for example), something like this: `find "$BACKUP_DIR" -mtime +14 -type f -name '*tgz' -delete`

Comment: Because I want to keep say a backup per month, and then a backup per fortnight, then one per week. Easiest way to do so without coding a full round robin system is deleting randomly, I thought.

Comment: I wouldn't want a backup when it depends on a coin toss whether I can restore my files. And when you say _delete 80% of the files randomly_ the odds are even worse.

Answer (score 1):

It uses a number of anti-patterns, but it does the trick on my server:

```
ls -U | shuf -n 100 | xargs rm -rf
```

where you can replace 100 by the number of files you want to delete.

Caution, though, because the deletion is random, you have no control over which files you are deleting. This situation is not ideal and a better backup strategy which is easier to maintain is preferred.

Comment: Here is my collection of backup scripts: https://github.com/pa4080/simple-backup-solutions

Comment: Thanks, those make a lot of sense. Taking note

Comment: Don't parse `ls`. See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead).